# Retriving project specific information stored in sonar Derby

Tags: derby, sonarqube

Please help me out to access the project specific information stored in my Sonar default server derby. As have very leass understading on it.

What I want to retrieve is very simple: it is just the information displayed on every sonar home page (http://localhost:9000/), that is to say the project name, the rules compliance indicator, the code coverage indicator and the build time...

Your guidance will be appreciable..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

You should not try to retrieve information directly from the database, for the DB is not an API and may change at any time without notice.

If you want to retrieve information stored by Sonar, please use Sonar [Web Service API](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API) instead.